# how to give type to this in typescript

Tags: typescript

```ts
function debounce(func: Function) {
    let timer: any;
    return function (...args: any) {
        const context = this;
        if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);

        timer = setTimeout(() => {
            timer = null;
            func.apply(context, args);
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

> `const context = this;`

is throwing type error for applying debounce concept in TS

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a function, and by default, the type of `this` in a function is `any`. Since you probably have your TypeScript configuration set up to not allow implicit `any` types, you have to explicitly inform the TypeScript compiler about the [`this` type for the function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#specifying-the-type-of-this-for-functions):

```
function debounce(func: Function) {
  let timer: any;
  return function (this: any, ...args: any) {
    const context = this;
    if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      timer = null;
      func.apply(context, args);
    }, 500);
  };
}
```

If you have more information about the [context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#function_context) in which the function will be called, you can specify a more narrow type than `any`.